# problem with succes and error messages Message module 'Friends'

Tags: solspace, solspace-friends

We have a problem with the way Messages to friends returns errors and succes message through the EE system.
We call the form in an iframe.
*(And solved form input errors with Jquery validation.)*

But the succes redirect still comes through EE. This makes the iframe collaps.
Is there a way to avoid the EE success page?

EDIT

We solved the collapsing of the iFrame by changing the errorpage. But the wish to avoid that standard EE success page still stands.
Is there a way to bypass it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, at this time the EE success page can't be avoided when submitting the {exp:friends:message_form} form. I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on. :)
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

Although it depends on your setup, you could perhaps try to submit the form in the background through ajax instead of moving away from the form to the success page after submission.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll submit a feature request. We avoided the problem by not using the iFrame. The referring link back (in the standard EE message) is dynamic filled in with right return page thanks to URL helper http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/url-helper since we call the message page from different places in the site.